# indexing in Xcode takes to long time

Tags: xcode

I have new very strange problem. If I want to run an app it will take to long time for indexing and other things... Sometimes It can take 15 minutes and more. The solution for this problem is clean a project and after that run it. but i need to shut off the xcode first and after that it will work. Has anybody else this problem? How to fix this problem? thanks

Comment: I've seen slightly longer index times, but nothing taking 15 minutes. What version of Xcode are you using? OS version?

Comment: Helpful post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392139/how-to-disable-indexing-in-xcode-4

Comment: @BillBrasky Xcode 4.0.2 OS version 4.3

Comment: That seems like an outdated version. Isn't Snow Leopard running 4.1?

Comment: I'd try removing Xcode and re-install, making sure you have latest version before you install.

Comment: I experienced numerous inconsistencies and minor bugs with 4.1 on Snow Leopard. Not this one, but many other slowdowns, crashes and irritations like this. As much as I hated to have to do it, a forced upgrade to a new machine running Lion and Xc 4.2 fixed all of them.

Comment: @TimKemp unfortunely i have macmini and it is not mine. I cannot update snow leopard to lion. But thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange but It works for me. I just go to Xcode ->Preferences and starting to push buttons in menu and building for my project is doing very fast