# Xcode indexing does not finish

Tags: xcode, indexing

I am having a small project just for testing. After a few days of testing the "indexing process" of Xcode broke, it simply does not finish. I tried it with another project, same thing. I tried to reinstall Xcode -> Did not help, I deleted the Derived Data -> Did not help. Restarting Mac + Xcode -> Did not help. Is there anything else I could try ? Thanks for every tip, this problem really kills the dev process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode stuck on Indexing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831559/xcode-stuck-on-indexing)

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the following has worked for several people.... Hope it helps you! PS:I'm trying it right now

1. Open your Project Folder.
2. Find ProjectName.xcodeproj file.
3. Right-Click Copy and Paste to Safe Place.
4. Right-Click Show Package Contents.
5. Find project.xcworkspace file and delete that file.
6. Reopen Your Project and clean and Rebuild.
7. If your problem is not solved than replace the file with your backup file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I solved that problem by just closing assistance editor and selecting another source file in Xcode. It was useless to empty /DerivedData folder, cleaning project, rebooting OS or reverting to the previous project. After closing assistance editor and selecting another source file in the project navigator, Xcode successfully completed the indexing. Before then I opened Info.plist with viewController.m source file in Assistance Editor. My Xcode version is 9.4.1.

Comment: Thanks. This solution still works for Xcode 12.5.