# watchOS 2 - How to select UIButtons randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm trying to select a number of interface elements on the watch randomly (e.g. from 20 UIButtons) in order to modify their properties color etc.

On the iPhone I would have had init a bunch of UIViews with numerical tags so I loop through them or use arcforrandom to select random squares. I understand that there is no tagging in watchkit interface elements. Is there another way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have tags to work with in WKInterfaceObjects and since you can't subclass the buttons to add properties or tags, the next best thing to do is do [what the Apple documentation suggests](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceButton_class/index.html):

> Do not subclass or create instances of this class yourself. Instead,
>   define outlets in your interface controller class and connect them to
>   the corresponding objects in your storyboard file. For example, to
>   refer to a button object in your interface, define a property with the
>   following syntax in your interface controller class:
>
> OBJECTIVE-C
>
> `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceButton* myButton;`

This means, unhappily, that you'll need about 20 `IBOutlets`.  You can then put these outlet pointers into an array that you can select from, randomly.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for answering. I tried the above already. When I tried to run, Xcode started to index, hung and was never able to build.

Comment: Indexing in Xcode (which usually happens when you launch Xcode or open a project) has nothing to do with building. Does that crash happen every time you build?

Comment: Yeah it's strange. If I comment out the IBOutlet array and clean then it indexes and builds. But otherwise it's just spin wheel and indexing completely unable to build.

Comment: [Here is a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831559/xcode-stuck-on-indexing) about the stuck on indexing problem.  A solution in there might help you out!

Comment: Maybe `IBOutletCollection` can avoid the need to create 20 `IBOutlet`.