# Xcode 8.1 stuck while trying to launch the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I'm facing problem while running a project in xcode 8.1. Xcode gets stuck during "Waiting for app to launch" process and it keeps loading forever. it does not throw any error also. Project builds fine but it isn't running on the simulator. I tried deleting the derived data. Tried deleting the .xcworkspace file.

I've looked upon these answers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834705/4863339

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16037836

These answers don't seem to be helping me much.

Comment: Did you tried `command` + `shift` + `K` and rebuild your project ?

Comment: In my case, quitting all applications followed by shutting down and then restarting of system worked!!

Some broken connection must have fixed itself on rebooting, I guess!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be that you disabled automatic start of the app?

Open your scheme via "Edit scheme..." menu, and make sure that "launch" setting in Run settings is set to Automatically.

[Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/CustomizingYourExperienceThroughXcodeSchemes/CustomizingYourExperienceThroughXcodeSchemes.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton! Changing it from "Wait for executable to be launched" to "Automatically" solved the issue.

Comment: My god, thanks man. I wasted 2 hours on this. Was thinking about reinstalling simulators

Answer (score 6):

For me restarting mac helped, nothing else I googled did.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting the simulator helped me in a similar situation.

Another case:
Xcode 12. Was stuck on device launch in debug after a while or on the first breakpoint.

Clean, deep clean (Command-Option-Shift-K), restart Xcode, remove the app from the device, run again.

Don't know which step exactly helped, but now all works as usual.

Comment: yap, restarting simulator fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've deleted xcuserdata. it helped in my case

```bash
rm -rf /pat/to/[YourProject].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata
```