# Xcode 9 keeps indexing at 100% of CPU

Tags: xcode, indexing

I have a project (objective C) that keeps being indexed by Xcode 9.2, and uses 100% of the CPU for hours.
Each time I quit Xcode, and restart, it starts to index again from scratch, even if NONE of the files has been modified. Are we serious about this?

I have the same project ported on Android Studio, and indexing is working fine.

It's not like it's new, Xcode has an indexing problem since ever, but seriously, we're talking about Xcode version 9, and it's worse than ever...

I've tried to remove pieces of my code, but's it's very difficult to investigate, I have to wait minutes to evaluate if it impacted the indexing, and it's very difficult to be sure. And of course I deactivated indexing, but no more code completion.
Totally discouraged by this, as I have the feeling nothing will fix it.

Comment: Maybe you can find some advise here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831559/xcode-stuck-on-indexing

Comment: Exposed a solution that kind of worked for me using cputhrottle here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53666638/612912