# Xcode 11 Beta 5 stuck indexing

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

I am using Xcode 11 Beta 5.  I have been using it since beta 1 on a different project.
I tried to create a new project, but Xcode goes straight to indexing.  If I delete that project and create a new project, it goes straight to indexing as well.
The same project builds on a co-worker's Mac using Xcode 11 Beta 5.  I am not using cocoa pods or Carthage in the project.

How can I get around this endless indexing?

I have tried several options, all to no avail.

I have tried the steps at this link, but they have not worked for me.  I'm hoping someone has some more recent experience with this problem.
[Xcode stuck on Indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831559/xcode-stuck-on-indexing)

- Reinstalled Xcode 11 Beta 5.
- Rebooted Mac.
- Deleted contents of derived Data folder.
- Deleted the project.xcworkspace and xcuserdata from the package
  contents.
- Completely deleted old project and created a new project with a
  different name.
- Copied derived data from a co-worker's Mac.

Comment: I tried everything in that link that you referenced.  That is why I am posting a new question.