# XCode 6 GM: Constantly freezing / locking while editing Swift code

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

Since installing XCode 6 GM, it has been freezing and locking, showing the spinning wheel of death while I attempt to edit code that has syntax errors.  Has anyone else seen this, and are there any known work-arounds?

I foolishly abandoned my cautious strategy of saving the previous version (Beta 7) and it appears that Beta 7 is no longer available for download.  Are there any known archives of / for the link?

I have also posted to the dev forums and will follow up with a bug report, but it is hard to pin down the exact circumstances.

## Edit:

**Additonal Notes:**

CPU: SourceKit Service is generally around 100%, but that has seem to have been the norm for the flavors of XCode, and the CPU seems to properly drop off when it finishes recompiling.

RAM: SourceKit is no longer exhibiting the memory leaks that used to cause it to halt and catch fire, memory does not appear to be a factor, and there are several ~ 5+ gigs to spare.

**Environment:**

Late 2012 Mac Mini, 16GB RAM 
OS X 10.9.4 (to be fair, this was new today as well, driven by the requirements of XCode 6 GM).

That said, only the software changed today.

## Update

Apple claims that this bug is fixed in Beta 6.1, for what it's worth.

Comment: I don't have this problem. You should provide the following info in your questions: 1) hardware details e.g. MBP or MBA, SSD drive or not 2) OSX version 3) Any Xcode related err message in Console?

Comment: @Anthony: Good point, done, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should look if you have any imports missing in your bridging header file. Sometimes even commented out imports will cause this behaviour. For me it was **commented out** Pixate Freestyle Cocoa Pod. I had to remove pod completely from my project to stop SourceKitService from crashing.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25173389/527539

Comment: This is absolutely true, there are a lot of things that causes this. The problem that caused it by me was a bad piece of code. It's really weird and hard to track down.

Comment: Yes, I am having this issue again suddenly... messes up not only syntax highlighting.. Probably going to look for 'malicious' code lines:)

Comment: fingers crossed, but updating to Version 6.1 (6A1046a) fixed all my SourceKitService prroblems

Answer (score 0):

I can't say any of these fixed the issue, but they alleviated the situation:

1. I removed all playgrounds from the project tree. Saved them somewhere else.
2. I removed all objectiveC code from the swift project (when possible). This Spinning-wheel, BTW, is a problem only in my swift projects. My other Objective-C-only projects are fine.
3. It looks like it's the background indexing process which is taking all the CPU. Open "Activity Monitor" and see it right there at the top, using 360% CPU. Lowering the priority for this process helped as well (type in terminal):

   renice 10 -p [pid]

   Make sure to take the correct process id from Activity Monitor. 
   The higher the number (should not exceed 19) the lower the priority.
4. I make significant changes one at a time. It seems that the amount of errors in the file affect how many times and for how long the spinning wheel spins. It looks like some type of errors trigger it more often than others, but I'm not able to pin point which exactly.

XCode had a similar indexing issue in previous versions (see this Xcode4 issue: [How to disable indexing in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5392139/2274829)) which gives me the hope they will fix this issue sometime, hopefully soon...

Answer (score 0):

I create a new tab via menu File->New Tab and close the old tab that is frozen.

CmdT does not work that time.

Comment: nobody is using Xcode 6 GM anymore. The bug has been already fixed in later releases.

Comment: I did not notice that it is GM. I am using Xcode 6.4 and it happens every day.

Comment: @VladimírSlavík faced with the same problem today. Do you know how to fix it? In my case looks like this issue related to magic mouse back gesture.

Comment: @Alexey It seems to be a plausible explanation. It looks like it is related to the navigation gesture. I will check that during development. Thank you.