# Xcode 6 constantly freezing

Tags: xcode, freeze

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

It constantly gets *Not Responding*.

Resources shouldn't be a problem (i7 2.2, 16 gb ram, SSD).

Xcode version: Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Standard procedure: Delete Derived Data folder and restart.

Comment: OS 10.9.5 build 13F34, macbook pro mid 2014

Comment: Thanks JoJoe. Seems to be working. For now at least :).

Comment: Doesn't seem to help that much. After 1-2 minutes it does the same thing again :|. PS: It freezes every time I try to edit something.

Comment: same problem here mac mini mid 13.

Comment: This is happening for me as well. 2014 MBP 2.3 GHz i7 with 16 GB RAM. I am using XCode 6.0.1 (6A317)

Comment: Check the steps listed here - perhaps one of them will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26027137/2274829

Comment: Thanks. I ended up not using Swift and that solved my problem :). Swift is still full of bugs and the compiler gets slower and slower as you add more code. It's a shame that it's not usable yet, because it is an elegant language.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. To resolve this:

```
1. Close Xcode
2. Open Terminal
3. Type defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
4. Re-open Xcode
```

Xcode is reset to its default settings - do NOT change appearance. It will never freeze again (at least mine hasn't). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run the following command:

`rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"`

Look for the following file in `~/Library/Caches` and delete it:
`com.apple.dt.Xcode`

Back in your terminal, run the following commands:

`rm -r Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

`rm -r Library/Developer/Xcode/xcuserdata`